# laravel - DI, Class not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, dependency-injection

I'm have created service for my application:
**ProductsShelfService**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Modules\ProductList\Services;

class ProductsShelfService
{
    public function sample()
    {
        return 'I am ProductsShelfService class!';
    }
}
```

and now I want to pass it to controller via DI:
**ProductListController**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Website\Pages;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Modules\ProductList\Services\ProductsShelfService;

class ProductListController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var ProductsShelfService
     */
    protected $shelfService;

    public function __construct(ProductsShelfService $shelfService)
    {
        $this->shelfService = $shelfService;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo $this->shelfService->sample();
    }
}
```

but I getting error:

```
ReflectionException
Class App\Modules\ProductList\Services\ProductsShelfService does not exist
```

Why? I need to do sth more?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it to ServiceContainer in Laravel

Step 1: create a ProductsShelfProvider

```
php artisan make:provider ProductsShelfProvider
```

Step 2: register your service in ProductsShelfProvider

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Modules\ProductList\Services\ProductsShelfService;

class ProductsShelfProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {

    }

    public function register()
    {
         $this->app->bind('App\Modules\ProductList\Services\ProductsShelfService', function ($app) {
            return new ProductsShelfProvider();
        });
    }
}
```

Step 3: declare in config/app

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Illuminate\View\ProductsShelfProvider::class,
]
```